# how to prevent blur shadow nodes from writing a mysterious number in nullfont?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, shadows, pgf-blur

I've isolated a weird font-related issue that's coming from a `blur shadow` tikz node, which appears to be writing the value of some mystery counter in nullfont.  The mystery counter starts at 17 and increments with each `blur shadow` node; non-`blur shadow` nodes do not seem to affect the mystery counter's value.  There are some values that seem to equal 17 in my log file, but when I included enough `blur shadow` nodes to get the mystery counter up to 29, then my log file didn't contain `29` anywhere in it, so I don't have any surviving theory about what's happening or how to avoid it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

% I get the following warnings when I xelatex this document:
%    Missing character: There is no 1 ("31) in font nullfont!
%    Missing character: There is no 7 ("37) in font nullfont!
%    Missing character: There is no 1 ("31) in font nullfont!
%    Missing character: There is no 8 ("38) in font nullfont!
%    Missing character: There is no 1 ("31) in font nullfont!
%    Missing character: There is no 9 ("39) in font nullfont!
%
% Alternatively, if I uncomment the following line, I see a giant 17, 18, and 19 in the output.
%   \font\nullfont=cmr24 

\begin{document}
\tikz{\node[draw, fill=white, blur shadow] {A};}  % Writes 17 [in nullfont]

\tikz{\node[draw, fill=white, blur shadow] {B};}  % Writes 18 [in nullfont]

\tikz{\node[draw, fill=white, blur shadow] {C};}  % Writes 19 [in nullfont]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX and good catch!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a bug in pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def. They mixed up the `\endcsname + \expandafter` order:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\makeatletter
\def\pgf@sys@pdf@install@mask#1{%
  \pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs{%
    /pgfsmask\csname pgfsmaskxform@#1\endcsname\space <<
      /SMask <<
        /S /Luminosity
        /G @pgfsmask\csname pgfsmaskxform@#1\endcsname
      >> >>}%<<
  %\expandafter\let\csname pgfsmask@#1\endcsname\expandafter\csname pgfsmaskxform@#1\endcsname%
  \expandafter\let\csname pgfsmask@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname pgfsmaskxform@#1\endcsname%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tikz{\node[draw, fill=white, blur shadow] {A};}  % Writes 17 [in nullfont]
%
\tikz{\node[draw, fill=white, blur shadow] {B};}  % Writes 18 [in nullfont]
%
\tikz{\node[draw, fill=white, blur shadow] {C};}  % Writes 19 [in nullfont]
\end{document}
```

I opened an issue https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1088